# Wanting to Override what is returned in WCF for EntityType Data

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco

I've got an entity defined called `SessionsOverview` in my model. I expose it through a WCF service with code like the following:

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
{
    // Examples:
    config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
    config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);
    config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
}
```

It creates a bunch of code in a file called `ModelSessionView.Designer.cs`

In that code, it currently has a method called `SessionsOverviews` that returns a .net object.  I'd like to override what is returned based on some security rules.  Specifically, I want to look in my app.config, get a setting, and if that setting is not true, I want to hide some of the data in this object.  I could just start updating this file, but that seems wrong.  Is there a clear place I should add logic like this?

Thanks

```
    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    public ObjectSet<SessionsOverview> SessionsOverviews
    {
        get
        {
            if ((_SessionsOverviews == null))
            {
                _SessionsOverviews = 
                  base.CreateObjectSet<SessionsOverview>("SessionsOverviews");
            }
            return _SessionsOverviews;
        }
    }
```

Comment: anyone have any ideas?  does my question not make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using QueryInterceptor's?

These get specified on the service class and return an expression that you can write your self.

A simple example is defined below:

```
[QueryInterceptor("SessionsOverviews")]
public Expression<Func<SessionsOverview, bool>> SessionsOverviewFilter()
{
    var configValue = readfromconfig;

    if (configValue == "something")
    {
        return (session) => session.thePropertyToFilteron == configValue;
    }

    return (session) => true;
}
```

Additionally you can also specify ChangeInterceptors.

See the following article for further details

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744842.aspx

Comment: is it possible to change the data ?? i got expression tree may not contain assignment operator error.

Comment: no the data returned from an interceptor must be of the type to be returned. In the above example the expression tree will be altered to have a where restriction applied to the final query. Something like where SessionsOverview.thePropertyToFilteron == 'foo'. There was a typo in the answer, appologies. It should be == rather than =.

Comment: not sure if it make sense, but if one were to manipulate the query result before sending it off (same type but alter the data). Where should this logic be implemented ? Prefer to have a strong type object to work against. thx

Comment: The interceptor adds a filter to the IQueryable object as this get executed only when you iterate through the results or call a greedy method on it you could alter the data anywhere. If you want to alter the physical data within the objects being returned then I would look at writing a service operation. This is just a method call in which you can alter data directly. http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/uri-conventions#AddressingServiceOperations